# QList copy constructor:how to new a QList<QStandardItem *> with variable

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I got a `QList<QString>` that reads and stores `QString` variables into a list like that:

```
QList<QString> itemlist;
```

Now I want to create a `QList<QStandardItem *>` from that `QString` list, I tried this:

```
QList<QStandardItem *> *items = new QList<QStandardItem *>(itemlist);
```

The compiler (vs2010) gives the error message that can not convert from "`QList<T>`" into "`const QList<T> &`"

Can anybody tell me how to do that?

Comment: oops, itemlist should be a QList<QString>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I'd write a brute force conversion function in **C++11**. It takes a const-ref to
`QList<QString>` and returns a `std::unique_ptr` to a `QList<QStandardItem*>`:

```
#include <QtCore/QList>
#include <QtGui/QStandardItem>

using ItemList = QList<QStandardItem*>;

std::unique_ptr<ItemList> toItemList(const QList<QString>& strings)
{
  std::unique_ptr<ItemList> items(new ItemList);

  for(auto& str : strings)
  {
    items->push_back(new QStandardItem(str));
  }

  return items;
}
```

**Example:**

```
QList<QString> strings;
strings.push_back("Hello");
strings.push_back("QStandardItem");

auto items = toItemList(strings);

for (auto item : *items.get())
{
  std::cout << item->text().toStdString() << std::endl;
}
```

**Output:**

```
Hello
QStandardItem
```

Please note: While the list itself is managed by a `std::unique_ptr`, the values are not manged in any way, i.e. you'll have to managed the allocated memory for all `QStandardItem`s yourself. Knowing Qt, however, I suspect you'll use the items in some model which manages deallocation.

Under other circumstances I'd have used a

- `std::unique_ptr<QList<std::unique_ptr<QStandardItem>>` or simply a
- `QList<QStandardItem>`

but neither is `QList` (in the version available to me) move-aware and cannot work with a value type of `std::unique_ptr<T>` (because its copy-ctor is deleted), nor is `QStandardItem`s copy-ctor public.

As an alternative, you could use a `std::unique_ptr<QList<std::shared_ptr<QStandardItem>>` and get a completely managed list of QStandardItems but you'd have to transfer ownership from the `std::shared_ptr` holding each item to the Qt model you're using.

Tested on Linux/g++-4.9

Comment: You gave a wonderful solution and explanation for exactly what I am asking. I took a for loop as you suggested and it worked fine. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @xlarry: Welcome! Please mark the question as answered.